How to Integrate Spring Boot with API Gateway using Midway Auth for Authentication?
I'm currently working on a project where I'm building a self-service portal using Spring Boot and Java. My goal is to integrate this portal with AWS services such as API Gateway and Lambda, while using Midway Auth for authentication
My challenge lies in properly configuring the integration between Spring Boot, API Gateway and Midway Auth. I'm particularly struggling with understanding how to handle authentication using Midway Auth and how to pass the generated access token.
Could someone provide guidance or a step-by-step example of how to achieve this integration? Any advice, code snippets would be greatly appreciated.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find much information about Midway Auth, its code snippets, features, or its API.

Can you tell more about the functionality of Midway Auth, what does it provide? is it different from say, Okta?

https://support.amazonstudios.com/hc/en-us/articles/22048144415636-Okta-and-Midway-FAQs.   Here you can find high level information
